# Segment resolving in AEM / CQ5 using initializeTeaserLoader adding multiple divs inside campaign target

Tags: aem

The below code is part of teaser.jsp (/libs/cq/personalization/components/teaser/teaser.jsp)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">$CQ(function() {
            initializeTeaserLoader(<%=allTeasers%>, "<%=strategy%>", "<%=targetDivId%>", "<%=(WCMMode.fromRequest(request) == WCMMode.EDIT)%>", "<%=trackingURLStr%>", "<%=resource.getPath()%>");
        });</script>
```

Similar code we used in our customized teaser jsp.

The above**initializeTeaserLoader** method is adding multiple divs inside the target div at the first time when offerpage is resolved.

Ideally it should have only one resolved div. Is there any solution for it?

Note: On page refresh functionality is working fine. But our application is single page application may be this issue is coming.

Comment: AFAIK it inserts the html of the resolved teaser inside the target div. Try using debug points to see where the extra divs are coming.

Comment: Can you refer existing **/libs/cq/personalization/components/teaser/teaser.jsp** code and tell me where exactly it will add the div?

Comment: @Abhishek  
Can you refer existing /libs/cq/personalization/components/teaser/teaser.jsp code and tell me where exactly it will add the div?

Comment: That is just the placeholder for the teaser component. If you inspect the code of initializeTeaserLoader, it will make an ajax call to your resolved teaser(offer) and insert into the DOM under the targetDiv. The html that gets inserted will be <yourResolvedOffer>/_jcr_content/par.html. If this html has its own extra divs, you need to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems to be an existing issue with OOTB teaser component.Apparently same thing happened in our project, we were using Angular Js on top of AEM (6.1).
We we went to ADOBE with a ticket and got one patch for the same problem (and few more, not relevant to this question).
Most probably if you go ahead and use 6.2, this problem should not persist.
Good LUCK (y)